# Delayed Job: Apply unsaved ActiveRecord object to something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I'm trying to apply an unsaved ActiveRecord object `Thing` to an array of saved objects `Person`.

```
person has_many :things
```

but Delayed Job isn't intended to work with unsaved ActiveRecord models.  I know because they told me:

> DJ isn't intended to work with unsaved ActiveRecord models.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-DJ_doesnt_deserialize_an_unsaved_ActiveRecord_model

...so I can't get around the error:

```
{ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, class: Thing , primary key:
```

I've been kicking around a few strategies to get around it:

1) Override self.yaml_new from [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb).  Sounds like a terrible idea.

2) Override `Thing.find` to recover from not found and just hydrate an unsaved object.  That's an even worse idea than #1

3) Save `Thing` to the db first.  Bad idea because we'll have an orphan `Thing` in the db that the Job will have to clean up (`Thing`s really don't exist without a `Person` attached), callers of the job will have to know to save the `Thing` first, and we'll have to override validations checking for `Person`.  Horrible.

4) Create `Thing.to_open_struct` method that'll dump the AR details into an OpenStruct for DJ serialization.  Kinda messy.  Need to keep that method in sync with any migrations.  Not ideal, but it's the best I have to far.

Any ideas?  I'm not set on DJ serializing the unsaved `Thing` I just want a clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to create a new table/model called UnsavedThing which doesn't have any associations but is basically the same as Thing.

DJ finds an UnsavedThing, uses it to call Thing.new, does stuff with it, calls Thing.save, and then UnsavedThing.destroy.

Not that elegant, but the alternatives aren't great either.

What is the reason you can't save Thing first? There might be a better solution if you can give more context of how the classes interact and the criteria for when Thing can be saved.

Comment: Re: "What is the reason you can't save Thing first?" I didn't want to muddle up the question any more. Let's just say that we can't do it.  Thanks for the idea about a different model.  Not bad.  I'll think about it for a bit.